# Problems with the output of an object in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am currently trying to get into Node.js and express. I am trying to create a simple bike configuration. For this I created an object that contains all the properties. I export this object and try to bring it to output in another script with select in index.html. Now when I start the web server I get this error message. My files are located in the client folder. But if I put the object in the bike.js everything works. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

```
var bikeArray = {
    Mountainbike: {
      Cross: {
        Größe: ["395 mm", "440 mm", "480 mm", "535 mm"],
        Farbe: ["Himmelblau", "Grasgrün", "Stahlgrau", "Weinrot"],
        Bremsen: [
          "Shimano Deore BRM6000",
          "Shimano Deore BRM7000",
          "Shimano RX810 1x11",
        ],
        Schaltung: [
          "Shimano GRX 600 2x11",
          "Shimano GRX 600 2x11",
          "Shimano GRX 810 Di2 2x11",
        ],
        Reifen: [
          "Continental X-King (35-622)",
          "Continental X-King RS (32-622)",
          "Continental Terra Trail (40-622)",
        ],
        Schutzblech: ["kein Schutzblech", "SKS Bluemels"],
        Schloss: [
          "kein Schloss",
          "AXA Faltschloss Fold 100",
          "Abus Faltschloss Bordo Granit X-Plus 6500/85",
        ],
        Licht: ["kein Lich", "Frontlicht", "Rücklicht", "Front- und Rücklicht"],
      },
      Hard: {
        Größe: ["395 mm", "440 mm", "480 mm"],
        Farbe: ["Himmelblau", "Grasgrün", "Stahlgrau", "Weinrot"],
        Bremsen: [
          "Shimano Deore BRM6000",
          "Shimano Deore BRM7000",
          "Shimano RX810 1x11",
        ],
        Schaltung: [
          "Shimano GRX 600 2x11",
          "Shimano GRX 600 2x11",
          "Shimano GRX 810 Di2 2x11",
        ],
        Reifen: [
          "Continental X-King (35-622)",
          "Continental X-King RS (32-622)",
          "Continental Terra Trail (40-622)",
        ],
        Schutzblech: ["kein Schutzblech", "SKS Bluemels"],
        Schloss: [
          "kein Schloss",
          "AXA Faltschloss Fold 100",
          "Abus Faltschloss Bordo Granit X-Plus 6500/85",
        ],
        Licht: ["kein Lich", "Frontlicht", "Rücklicht", "Front- und Rücklicht"],
      },
      Up: {
        Größe: ["440 mm", "2480 mm", "535 mm"],
        Farbe: ["Himmelblau", "Grasgrün", "Stahlgrau", "Weinrot"],
        Bremsen: [
          "Shimano Deore BRM6000",
          "Shimano Deore BRM7000",
          "Shimano RX810 1x11",
        ],
        Schaltung: [
          "Shimano GRX 600 2x11",
          "Shimano GRX 600 2x11",
          "Shimano GRX 810 Di2 2x11",
        ],
        Reifen: [
          "Continental X-King (35-622)",
          "Continental X-King RS (32-622)",
          "Continental Terra Trail (40-622)",
        ],
        Schutzblech: ["kein Schutzblech", "SKS Bluemels"],
        Schloss: [
          "kein Schloss",
          "AXA Faltschloss Fold 100",
          "Abus Faltschloss Bordo Granit X-Plus 6500/85",
        ],
        Licht: ["kein Lich", "Frontlicht", "Rücklicht", "Front- und Rücklicht"],
      },
    },
    Ebike: {
      Cloud: {
        Größe: ["420 mm", "460 mm", "520 mm"],
        Farbe: ["Himmelblau", "Grasgrün", "Stahlgrau", "Weinrot"],
        Bremsen: ["Shimano Deore Disc Trekking", "Shimano Deore XT Disc"],
        Schaltung: [
          "Shimano E6100",
          "Shimano E6100 Alfine",
          "Shimano EP8 Deore XT",
        ],
        Akku: ["504 Wh Akku und 4A Ladegerät"],
        Reifen: [
          "Continental X-King (35-622)",
          "Continental X-King RS (32-622)",
          "Continental Terra Trail (40-622)",
        ],
        Schutzblech: ["kein Schutzblech", "SKS Bluemels"],
        Schloss: [
          "kein Schloss",
          "AXA Faltschloss Fold 100",
          "Abus Faltschloss Bordo Granit X-Plus 6500/85",
        ],
        Licht: ["kein Lich", "Frontlicht", "Rücklicht", "Front- und Rücklicht"],
      },
      Speedy: {
        Größe: ["420 mm", "460 mm", "520 mm"],
        Farbe: ["Himmelblau", "Grasgrün", "Stahlgrau", "Weinrot"],
        Bremsen: ["Shimano Deore Disc Trekking", "Shimano Deore XT Disc"],
        Schaltung: [
          "Shimano E6100",
          "Shimano E6100 Alfine",
          "Shimano EP8 Deore XT",
        ],
        Akku: ["504 Wh Akku und 4A Ladegerät"],
        Reifen: [
          "Continental X-King (35-622)",
          "Continental X-King RS (32-622)",
          "Continental Terra Trail (40-622)",
        ],
        Schutzblech: ["kein Schutzblech", "SKS Bluemels"],
        Schloss: [
          "kein Schloss",
          "AXA Faltschloss Fold 100",
          "Abus Faltschloss Bordo Granit X-Plus 6500/85",
        ],
        Licht: ["kein Lich", "Frontlicht", "Rücklicht", "Front- und Rücklicht"],
      },
      Chilli: {
        Größe: ["420 mm", "460 mm", "520 mm"],
        Farbe: ["Himmelblau", "Grasgrün", "Stahlgrau", "Weinrot"],
        Bremsen: ["Shimano Deore Disc Trekking", "Shimano Deore XT Disc"],
        Schaltung: [
          "Shimano E6100",
          "Shimano E6100 Alfine",
          "Shimano EP8 Deore XT",
        ],
        Akku: ["504 Wh Akku und 4A Ladegerät"],
        Reifen: [
          "Continental X-King (35-622)",
          "Continental X-King RS (32-622)",
          "Continental Terra Trail (40-622)",
        ],
        Schutzblech: ["kein Schutzblech", "SKS Bluemels"],
        Schloss: [
          "kein Schloss",
          "AXA Faltschloss Fold 100",
          "Abus Faltschloss Bordo Granit X-Plus 6500/85",
        ],
        Licht: ["kein Lich", "Frontlicht", "Rücklicht", "Front- und Rücklicht"],
      }
    }
  };

  module.exports = bikeArray;
```

bike.js

```
var bikeArray = require('./mock');

console.log(bikeArray.model);
window.onload = function () {
  var typSel = document.getElementById("typSel"),
    modelSel = document.getElementById("modelSel"),
    sizeSel = document.getElementById("sizeSel"),
    colorSel = document.getElementById("colorSel"),
    breakSel = document.getElementById("breakSel"),
    tireSel = document.getElementById("tireSel");

  for (var typ in bikeArray) {
    typSel.options[typSel.options.length] = new Option(typ, typ);
  }
  //Give Model
  typSel.onchange = function () {
    modelSel.length = 1; 
    sizeSel.length = 1;
    if (this.selectedIndex < 1) return; 
    for (var model in bikeArray[this.value]) {
      modelSel.options[modelSel.options.length] = new Option(model, model);
    }
  };

  typSel.onchange();

  //Give Size
  modelSel.onchange = function () {
    sizeSel.length = 1;
    colorSel.length = 1;
    if (this.selectedIndex < 1) return; 
    var size = bikeArray[typSel.value][this.value];
    console.log(size);
    for (var s = 0; s < size.Größe.length; s++) {
      sizeSel.options[sizeSel.options.length] = new Option(
        size.Größe[s],
        size.Größe[s]
      );
    }
  };
  //Give Color
  sizeSel.onchange = function () {
    colorSel.length = 1;
    breakSel.length = 1;
    if (this.selectedIndex < 1) return; 
    var color = bikeArray[typSel.value][modelSel.value];
    console.log(color);
    for (var c = 0; c < color.Farbe.length; c++) {
      colorSel.options[colorSel.options.length] = new Option(
        color.Farbe[c],
        color.Farbe[c]
      );
    }
  };

  //Give Breaks
  colorSel.onchange = function () {
    breakSel.length = 1;
    tireSel.length = 1;
    if (this.selectedIndex < 1) return; 
    var breaks = bikeArray[typSel.value][modelSel.value];
    console.log(breaks);
    for (var b = 0; b < breaks.Bremsen.length; b++) {
      breakSel.options[breakSel.options.length] = new Option(
        breaks.Bremsen[b],
        breaks.Bremsen[b]
      );
    }
  };

  //Give Tires
  breakSel.onchange = function () {
    tireSel.length = 1;
    if (this.selectedIndex < 1) return;
    var tires = bikeArray[typSel.value][modelSel.value];
    for (var t = 0; t < tires.Reifen.length; t++) {
      tireSel.options[tireSel.options.length] = new Option(
        tires.Reifen[t],
        tires.Reifen[t]
      );
    }
  };
};
```

app.js

```
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');

const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));
const server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(4000, () => {
    console.log('Server listening on port 4000');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here : `var bikeArray = require('./mock');` **you're using CommonJS (CJS) modules**, which is the module specification used by default *[1]* in Node.js for working with modules.

**In browsers, CJS is not supported and ECMAScript modules (ESM) should be used**. They are the official standard format to package JavaScript code for reuse.

**Bike.js is used in index.html. It runs when index.html is opened in the browser, so it runs on the browser, not in Node. Therefore, it should use ESM.**
Here is a course about using modules in the browser : https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-use-javascript-modules-in-the-browser.

**For your issue, you need to:**

In Bike.js, change the `require` to :

```
import bikeArray from "./mock.js";
```

In mock.js, change the `module.exports` to:

```
export default bikeArray;
```

And in index.html, change the script tag to :

```
<script src="./bike.js" type="module"></script>
```

**Some ressources :**

Here is a short article about ESM : https://flaviocopes.com/es-modules/

MDN documentation about modules : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules

The "Eloquent JavaScript" (great book) chapter on modules: https://eloquentjavascript.net/10_modules.html

---

*[1]* With the release of Node version 15.3.0, ES modules are supported (see https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_determining_module_system for how to use one or the other).

Comment: Thank you it works perfectly :)